# How to shorten a line with points A B

Tags: javascript, math

I have a line segments with points A and B.
I want the points of a shorter line segment.

Maybe I can use the slope dX / dY, but there is an exception when dY is 0.
Also how to represent this line to keep these operations simple?

Comment: If you have an exception - treat it as an exception. This is what programming is about - thinking of different cases.

Comment: What do you mean by a shorter line? All lines are infinitely long. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach avoiding the need to deal with exceptions. It even works in the degenerate case of A and B being the same point.

If you have a line segment from points A to B, and you want to make it a fraction `t` (e.g. `t=0.1`) shorter on both sides, you can calculate two new points:

```
C = (1 - t) * A + t * B
D = t * A + (1 - t) * B
```

And draw the line segment between these new points. In 2D you need to do the calculation for both the `x` and the `y` component. In 3D you'll also need to calculate the `z` component. As this is a linear combination, C and D will lie on the line AB.

Note that the same approach can be used to prolong the line segment, by choosing t smaller than 0 or larger than 1.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No further answers are necessary.